# UrlFetchApp.fetch triggered from Sheets event failing for lack of permissions but works when run directly

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have a google apps scripts hosted in a Google Sheets sheet, that runs UrlFetchApp.fetch, for several things (authenticating with GCP service account, invoking GCP apis, etc).

The thing is, if I run it or debug it directly from the script editor (menu Run -> Run function / Debug function) it works fine, but when I attach it to an event handler like "onEdit" it fails, at the "Apps Script Dashboard" I can see this error

> You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch. Required
>   permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
>   at unknown function at getBearerToken(Code:24) at
>   writeToBigquery(Code:40) at onEdit(Code:15)

However, I have the given scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request both as manifest and at script properties, and the script itself (even the onedit with hardcoded values runs fine when launched directly).

Following the manifest:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],

  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

And a script file extract follows:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // var range = e.range;
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1");
  // var row = range.rowStart;
  var row = 2;
  var cols = ['C', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R'];
  var data = new Object();
  for (var ii = 0; ii < cols.length; ii++)
  {
     data[cols[ii]] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cols[ii] + row.toString()).getValue();
  }
  Logger.log('calling writeToBigquery');
  writeToBigquery(data);
}

// uses the wonderful library https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-GSApp-Library to oauth against a GCP service account
function getBearerToken() {

  var jsonKey = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("json_key"));
  var key = jsonKey.private_key;
  var clientEmail = jsonKey.client_email;
  var serverToken = new GSApp.init(key, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.insertdata'], clientEmail);
  // requestToken invokes UrlFetchApp according to https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-GSApp-Library/blob/master/GSApp.gs, line 120
  serverToken.addUser(clientEmail).requestToken();
  var token = serverToken.getToken(clientEmail);
  Logger.log(token);
  return token.token;
}

function uuidv4() {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
  });
}

function writeToBigquery(obj)
{
  Logger.log('requesting bearer token');
  // fails in this line
  var token = getBearerToken();
  // lots of other irrelevant stuff
  // ...
}
```

As mentioned, when ran directly from the script editor works fine, its just failing when ran by triggering it thru user interaction in the Google Sheet.

Also the user editing the Google Sheet is not necessarily a user with rights in the GCP project (that's why a service account is used).